# Linux howto/tutorial/help sites?

Tags: linux, tutorial

I've found [HowtoForge](http://www.howtoforge.com/) very helpful. Is there any other similar sites that doesn't have too old tutorials which won't work nowadays?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find that the **Ubuntu community** is very active, and hence there howtos are generally quite recent.

http://ubuntuforums.org would be the direct route

but I find that just adding the word **"Ubuntu"** to my google search will often put those results at the top, and find exactly what I'm looking for without having to re-search their site.

Comment: hmm.. Organization of the topic is great

Answer (score 4):

I find [Linux Questions](http://www.linuxquestions.org) very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The BEST howto I've seen so far is a *one-off* site for setting up a **mail filtering gateway server**

You can find the howto [here](http://www200.pair.com/mecham/spam/)

I've often thought that site would be a good model for what a howto site should be like.

Comment: great site indeed, but they miss one bit - fuzzyocr for spamassasin - http://www.howtoforge.com/fight_image_spam_with_fuzzyocr_spamassassin . it really mitigates image spam well.

Answer (score 2):

Debian wiki is also pretty awesome. Doesn't cover everything but what it does cover, it covers it really well.

wiki.debian.org

On a side note, I tend to disagree that howtoforge has outdated tutorials... It's maybe true that they are specified for an older version of Ubuntu/Debian but they usually work for the newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do. [TLDP](http://tldp.org/sorted_howtos.html) updates frequently.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to TLDP and, to a lesser extent, Ubuntu forums, I have had great luck with the gentoo documentation.  By and large all configuration is described using the config files, instead of tools.  Typically, so long as you translate the installation steps, everything else should apply.

Official Docs:  http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/
Community Docs: http://gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Main_Page

Answer (score 1):

The [arch linux](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Main_Page) documentation can be a great resource if you want to know how a package works, obviously this is applicable to arch however alot of the stuff is relevant to other distros.

Answer (score 1):

I have found good articles on Linux Planet: [**http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/**](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/)

Also, the Linux Documentation project has a lot of updated info: [**http://tldp.org/**](http://tldp.org/)

Answer (score 1):

i have noticed [linux.com](http://linux.com) finially launched recently, i imagine they would have good content.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to wade through some of the stuff, but you may find this site worthwhile:

- [ShowMeDo](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/linux) - Showmedo is about learning and (Free and) Open-source software (FOSS). We were inspired to start Showmedo by watching some very effective web video-tutorials/screencasts.

Look for the "Installing and using Linux" or the Ubuntu series.

*Note: don't be put off by all the dev stuff...*

Answer (score 0):

By far the most useful howto site for Linux Admin I have found is HowtoForge followed closely by "debian administration"